# Create a field with conditions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm a beginner in django rest framework.

I am wondring if there is a way to create a field from a GET. For example if "count" == 0, create a field named "available" : "out_of_stock" else "available

**models.py**

```
class Count(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    count = models.IntergerField()
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Count
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
class CountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Count.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CountSerializer
```

**output**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "count": 10,
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "count": 0,
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you provide the serializer you are certainly using to serialize the `{ "id": ..., "count": ... }` part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, for a good practise, avoid using `fields = '__all__'` and instead define your fields specifically.

For ex: `fields = ['name', 'count']`, you will see doing so will pay off shortly as I continue.

DRF has the feature to mark a serializer field as `read_only` or `write_only` so it works on specific requests, as it looks from the naming **read_only intended for GET** and **write_only for POST**.

You can do what you are looking for in so many ways, but I think the easiest way to do it would be using [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) like this:

```
class CountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    available = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_available((self, obj):
        value = 'out_of_stock' if obj.count == 0 else 'available'
        return value

    class Meta:
        model = Count
        fields = ['name', 'count', 'available']
```

For more advanced needs, you can read about dynamic serializer fields on drf docs, [see](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields).